# Can I export metrics from Prometheus exporter directly to Cloud Monitoring?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I found I can send metrics from Prometheus instance to Cloud Monitoring [using sidecar project](https://github.com/Stackdriver/stackdriver-prometheus-sidecar). That's good, but I'd like to skip this step.
Can I just point Cloud Monitoring to a known network URL to get infro from regular prometheus exporter (**like Prometheus server does**) or is it a push based system only? 
I scanned [docs on custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census) several times, haven't found a solution. They show only a way to push metric data from your app

Comment: explain votes to close, please - if it's a duplicate, point me to the earlier question

Comment: currently, it seems to be supported only on k8s and by a small set of exporters: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/exporters/introduction